# When does python raise a FloatingPointError?

Tags: python

Python documentation says that FloatingPointError is raised when a float calculation fails. But what is exactly meant here by *"a float calculation"*?
I tried adding, multiplying and dividing with floats but never managed to raise this specific error. Instead, i got a `TypeError`:

```
10/'a'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'
```

Can someone help me understand when a `FloatingPointError` is raised in python?

Comment: Just [read the IEEE floating-point standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) to understand what kind of operation fail. Something like ```1.0/0.0``` for example will raise an exception (divide by zero)!

Comment: @sascha this would be a `ZeroDivisionError` error though.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Interesting design decision. But well, you are right!

Comment: On a second thought, i like the question..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis If you use `fpectl.turnon_sigfpe` to intercept floating point arithmetic "Division by Zero, Overflow, or Invalid Operation" are (or may) be turned into `FloatingPointError`.

Comment: @MSeifert My understanding at this point is that the `FloatingPointError` is like a *superset* formed as the *union* of the individual errors. By default, Python raises the detailed error descriptions (e.g., `ZeroDivisionError`) but this behaviour can be set by using `fpectl.turnon_sigfpe`.

Answer (score 15):

It is part of the [`fpectl`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fpectl.html) module. The [`FloatingPointError`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fpectl.html#fpectl.FloatingPointError) shouldn't be raised if you don't explicitly turn it on (`fpectl.turnon_sigfpe()`).

However mind the note:

> The `fpectl` module is not built by default, and its usage is discouraged and may be dangerous except in the hands of experts.  See also the section `fpectl-limitations` on limitations for more details.

Update: The `fpectl` module has been [removed as of Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#module-removals).

---

Even with FloatingPointErrors turned on, `10/'a'` will never raise one. It will always raise a TypeError. A FloatingPointError will only be raised for operations that reach the point of actually performing floating-point math, like `1.0/0.0`. `10/'a'` doesn't get that far.

Comment: Thanks @Mseifert but i quite did not get it.If i have understood it correct it means that it would never be raised unless I turn it on?

Comment: @SudeahKrishna Actually anyone could manually raise a [`FloatingPointError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FloatingPointError). But the standard libraries won't raise them if python isn't compile with `--with-fpectl` and you manually set `fpectl.turnon_sigfpe()` (and even then it might not work on your computer because that module is highly OS-specific).

Comment: How can i compile it with ``--with-fpect1`` as i can not even import the module ``fpect1``.I tried on CentOS6 and Windows10 as well

Comment: @SudeahKrishna I assume you can't just compile the `fpectl` module, I assume you need to build **Python from source** and use `./configure --with-fectl`.

Answer (score 6):

You can also trigger a `FloatingPointError` within `numpy`, by setting the appropriate [`numpy.seterr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) (or [`numpy.errstate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html#numpy.errstate) context manager) flag.  For an example taken from the documentation:

> ```
> >>> np.sqrt(-1)
> nan
> >>> with np.errstate(invalid='raise'):
> ...     np.sqrt(-1)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
> FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in sqrt
> ```

Interestingly, it also raises `FloatingPointError` when all operands are integers:

> ```
> >>> old_settings = np.seterr(all='warn', over='raise')
> >>> np.int16(32000) * np.int16(3)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> FloatingPointError: overflow encountered in short_scalars
> ```

The documentation notes the conditions under which the `FloatingPointError` will be raised:

> The floating-point exceptions are defined in the IEEE 754 standard [1]:
>
> - Division by zero: infinite result obtained from finite numbers.
> - Overflow: result too large to be expressed.
> - Underflow: result so close to zero that some precision was lost.
> - Invalid operation: result is not an expressible number, typically indicates that a NaN was produced.